# How to stop centered changing text from moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I have downloaded a text rotator plugin. Works great but there is a small issue with it. Every time it changes text the whole heading moves becuse it's centered. 
A simple example here: (Don't mind the js code, It's just a simplified example of the plugin)

HTML

```
<h1>
Heading <span class="change">Change</span>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
var itr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var  interval = 1000; //one second
itr.forEach((itr, index) => {
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.change').text('Car');
            setTimeout(() => {
            $('.change').text('Boat');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                    $('.change').text('Helicopter');
                    }, index * interval
                   );
          }, index * interval
         );
  }, index * interval
 );
})
```

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/teku3a0w/1/

**Is there a way to stop the heading from moving when it changes?** 
Permanent margin would definitely be an answer but i want it to be responsive.

Comment: *"responsible"*, you mean responsive? Heading moves? Moves where? Are you having problem when a long text suddenly spans two lines (therefore changing the height of header)?

Comment: `text-align:center` will set the center of the elements expansion point in the center and dynamically change the width to expand per width of its content.  Sounds like you want the parent div to margin to center and hold a left expansion point for your text-align. You could define the margin in % on your h1 parents div and then align-text on the h1 to be default left hand.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it isn't really responsive. For example 20% on computer is really different from 20% on phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution to this myself.

```
.change{
  display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I added a fixed width to the part thats changing.
Note that the width has to be big enough to contain the longest word in the list.

 You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqpj2zc/

Answer (score 0):

here are the changes I made to the HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<h1>
  <span>Heading</span>
  <span style = 'padding-left: 6px' class="change">Change</span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  span.change {
    width: 150px
  }
}
```

These are fixed widths, so this solution isn't really that flexible. But you might have a better time putting the longest word to be displayed first, grabbing that width, and setting the width of `span.change` to be a little bigger than that.

I set my media query to 768px since that's a good size to start considering tablet-sized screens and above.

This approach might not be the best solution, but it's still something :)